# Searching from one table to show details from second table with relation based on id

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables sales, users. I am trying to make a search query.

My `sales.userId = user.id`

I have following code

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `fullname`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `storename`, `storeAddress`, `imagePath`, `creationDate`, `updatedTime`, `comments`, `isFirstTime`, `graceUsed`, `salesCount`) VALUES


if(isset($_GET["q"]) && $_GET["q"]!="")
{
    $q = trim($_GET["q"]);
    $where = "WHERE (users.fullname like '%".$q."%' OR users.email like '%".$q."%' AND sales.userId = users.id)";
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM sales, users ".$where." order by sales.id DESC";
$records = db::getRecords($query, getCursor(), $pageSize);
```

NOw i am not getting how can i co relate the users table with sales.userId in my query to make the "WHERE" Clause work

Comment: why you use users.fullname meanwhile in your $query you just select one table is sales ?

Comment: @Nucleo1985 yes that's what i need, how to select the second table. using ids along with parameter

Comment: SELECT bla bla FROM sales, users ".$where." order by sales.id DESC" and change 'bla bla with field name from both tables ?

Comment: @Nucleo1985 i have tried this already. I also added the query like below answer. It still says fullname column not found or email column not found

Comment: Can you show your table structure ?

Comment: @Nucleo1985 check the edits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64671/discussion-between-nucleo-1985-and-muhammad-umar).

Comment: Try declared one column select for users, like SELECT *, users.fullname FROM.... and var_dump the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraint needs to make sure the users from the sales are the same as the ones from the search query
`$where = "WHERE (users.fullname like '%".$q."%' OR users.email like '%".$q."%') AND sales.userID = users.id "`

You can also do a join:
`'SELECT * FROM sales INNER JOIN users ON users.id = sales.userId WHERE user.fullname LIKE %'.$q.'%'.' OR user.email LIKE %'.$q.'%'`

Comment: Unknown column 'users.fullname' in 'where clause'

Comment: You need to include the users table in the from

Comment: that's what i am asking... how.

Comment: that's weird, i try echoing the query with join and it works fine in phpmyadmin but still giving same error in my code. Let me check out what is problem and i get back.

Comment: it gives you fullname unknown column?